# how to correlate the two AI’s telemetry data of Front End calls and Web API calls using correlation feature

Tags: azure, correlation, azure-application-insights

I had **Angular2** and **Asp.Net Web API** applications for that I configured the Application Insights Resource for tracking custom telemetry of those applications. But I used two different AI keys, one for Angular2 application and one for Web API application.

I used to [correlation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/application-insights-correlation) feature to correlate the Two Applications Insights telemetry of Front End calls and Web API calls but operation ID did not match.

Can you please tell me how to correlate the two AI’s telemetry of Front End calls and Web API calls using correlation feature.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Fixing per the additional information in comment.**

You sound like you want to correlate the *dependent requests* with the server request. This is usually handled by the combination of two pieces:

1. Set `disableCorrelationHeaders = false` in the JavaScript snippet config
2. Ensure your API Service has the [`OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/v2.3.0/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer.cs) added in the ApplicationInsights.config under the `<TelemetryInitializers>` section

The JavaScript setting will set the `x-ms-request-id` and the `x-ms-request-root-id` header to be picked up by the telemetry initializer.

The [initializer relies](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/v2.3.0/Src/Web/Web.Shared.Net/OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer.cs#L46) on the HttpContext.Request being available.

Using separate instrumentation keys (iKeys) will not matter when it comes to setting the operation id. Where it will matter is when you go to look for this correlated telemetry in the UI. If everything flows to the same iKey it will be able to be retrieved.

The next thing to be mindful of is if your server side telemetry is being sampled. By default the AdaptiveSampling processor is enabled and set to only send 5 telemetry items per second.

**Steps to troubleshoot**

1. When the request is sent from the browser use Fiddler or the F12 tools to ensure the `x-ms-request-*` headers are being set.
2. Debug your WebAPI application and validate that `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-ms-request-id"]` or `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-ms-request-root-id"]` is present
3. Ensure `<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>` is added in the `<TelemetryInitializers>` section of your ApplicationInsights.config
4. Increase the `<MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>` to a large number like 5000
5. Make sure you're using v2.2.0 or higher of the .NET SDK

Comment: I already tried with this link and set disableCorrelationHeaders to false in typescript. but I am not getting any correlation between my Angular2 application AI and API app AI telemetry. currently I am using ng2-appinsights module in Angular2 application, this will support correlation or not in Angular Application?

Comment: Thanks Davis, you saved a lot time on this issue.

Comment: After implemented your answer in my application, the correlation occurs between Angular2 application  AI telemetry and API app AI telemetry only when I run the application in my local machine but after published my entire application into azure web app, API app it's not occurred the correlation between angular application AI telemetry and API app AI telemetry.

Comment: "Make sure you're using v2.2.0 or higher of the .NET SDK" Does this mean the version of any AppInsight nuget package or the .net version itself? Will this work in .Net 4.6.1 WebAPI project?

Comment: @JamesDavis-MSFT I was having a correlation issue with data I am sending to appInsights. I was troubleshooting and your steps are indeed helpful.  However, I came across this Github mentioning that those x-ms-request* headers were deprecated in AppInsights (https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/issues/887).  Do you have any updated suggestions for troubleshooting because I am stuck with requests and customEvents that I want to correlate, but can't seem to figure out how to.